# Rail6 db:migrate fails - wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, dbmigrate

I am unable to create tables (i.e. run db:migrate successfully) in Rail 6 on Windows 7.

Just in case I completely reinstalled rails by Installing Ruby 2.6 development pack and doing a 'gem install rails' which for me installed Rails 6.0.3.1

I created a new project and the first thing did was generate a 'Customer' model after which I ran the db:migrate command immediately after it failed saying the 'wrong number of arguments were given'. See below.

```
C:\Apps\rails>cd cmdb

C:\Apps\rails\cmdb>rails generate model Customer string:name

      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb
      create    app/models/customer.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/customer_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/customers.yml

C:\Apps\rails\cmdb>rails db:migrate

== 20200525080817 CreateCustomers: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:customers)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:4:in `block in change'
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:4:in `block in change'
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

The migration.rb was generated and is shown below:-



class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]

  def change

    create_table :customers do |t|

      t.name :string

      t.timestamps
    end

  end

end
```

The re-run with a full trace is pasted below:-

```
C:\Apps\rails\cmdb>rails db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20200525080817 CreateCustomers: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:customers)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:4:in `block in change'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:309:in `create_table'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:890:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:858:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:858:in `say_with_time'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:879:in `method_missing'
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:3:in `change'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:828:in `exec_migration'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:812:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:811:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:471:in `with_connection'

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:810:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1002:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1310:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `block in ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `block in tra
nsaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:280:in `block in within_new_
transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in
 synchronize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchroniz
e'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transacti
on'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `transaction'

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1309:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1281:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `migrate_without_lock'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1231:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:4:in `block in change'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:309:in `create_table'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:890:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:858:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:858:in `say_with_time'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:879:in `method_missing'
C:/Apps/rails/cmdb/db/migrate/20200525080817_create_customers.rb:3:in `change'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:828:in `exec_migration'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:812:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:811:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:471:in `with_connection'

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:810:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1002:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1310:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `block in ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `block in tra
nsaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:280:in `block in within_new_
transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in
 synchronize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchroniz
e'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transacti
on'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `transaction'

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1309:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1281:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1280:in `migrate_without_lock'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1231:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

C:\Apps\rails\cmdb>
```

Comment: for further info.
I'm in the development environment using SQLITE3 which is installed.

C:\Apps\rails\cmdb>sqlite3 --version
3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54 3bfa9cc97da10598521b342961df8f5f68c7388fa117345eeb516eaa837bb4d6

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone else is wondering why else this could be:
I generated a migration with the same name as my model and started to get `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class MyCustomClassName` error. Then I renamed the migration class to `CreateMyCustomClassNameTable` but left its file name the same `20201217095257_my_custom_class_name.rb` which produced `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)` error. Renaming file to `20201217095257_create_my_custom_class_name_table.rb` fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have generated migration wrongly.

The column name comes first and it's data type follows it. Compare following with the command you used.

```
rails generate model Customer name:string
```

You can quickly fix it by running

```
rails destroy model Customer
```

and then re generate migration using the `generate` command I shared above.

Comment: Much appreciated Amit - you're a star.

Comment: Just go to the migration file and change it instead of destroying the model completely ??

Comment: `rails g model` does a lot of things. so undo it and redo as mentioned would make life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue, below is the error that I got:

```
-- create_table(:workers)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/db/migrate/20210516062205_create_workers.rb:9:in `block in change'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/db/migrate/20210516062205_create_workers.rb:3:in `change'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/db/migrate/20210516062205_create_workers.rb:9:in `block in change'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/db/migrate/20210516062205_create_workers.rb:3:in `change'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/wint3r/Learn/RubyOnRails/AssetManager/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

In my case issue occurred because I tried to use t.timestamps for a custom datetime field 'emp_joining_date', I solved it by changing the type from t.timestamps to t.datetime